# Confirm Box in Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, asp.net, .net

CODE

```
protected void btnSelectInvioces_Click(object source, EventArgs 
{
    try
    {
        // some code here
        if(a == b)
        {
            // open confirmation box
            if(OK)  // i click ok button of confirm box
            {
                // proceed further...
            }
        }
    } 
    catch()
    { }
}
```

I need to have a Confirm box only when satisfying a condition from server side.

I tried using `RegisterClientScript`.

What is happening is, it is executing my whole code and then giving me pop up.

BUT, I want to open popup at certain point. When it opens, further code should not be executed unless and until I click OK/Cancel button of that confirmation box

Comment: It doesn't work like that, server side code doesn't hold to complete a client side validation. Make an AJAX call after the confirmation box

Comment: Do you use ajaxtoolkit in your application?

Answer (score 0):

using javascript like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    function ConfirmBox() {
      if (confirm("Continue?")) {
            alert("Yes");
        } else {
            alert("No");
     }
  }
```

```
<asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Button" OnClick="Button1_Click" />
```

And in the code behind you can use `ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript` like this:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "ConfirmBox", "ConfirmBox();", true);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your confirm box is client side. And the code that you shown is server side.

You need ajax for this purpose. If you need help there then let me know.

Remember alert, confirm and other things that are offered by your browser is client side. In your javascript you can do something like this,

```
if(confirm("press OK"))
 { ajax call }
```

in ajax call you can execute your server side code that starts after your condition if(OK)

Answer (score 0):

You can use Ajax Confirm button extender with full customization [`http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx`](http://www.ajaxcontroltoolkit.com/ConfirmButton/ConfirmButton.aspx)

Or if you want to call in between button click process with code condition then u can use

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(this, this.GetType(), "ajax", "callconfirm()", true);
```

if you get ok then call with your ajax

```
if(confirm("OK")) { ajax call }
```

Answer (score 0):

First add a hidden field, and set its value based on user pressed confirmation button

**Html Markup:**

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="HiddenField1" runat="server" />
```

---

**Client side:** Set the result in hidden field

```
function ConfirmMessage() {

        if (confirm("Are you sure ?")) {
            $("#HiddenField1").val("Yes");
        } else {
             $("#HiddenField1").val("No");
        }
    }
```

---

**Code-behind:** Retrieve the hidden field value and make your call

```
string confirmValue = HiddenField1.Value
  if (confirmValue == "Yes")
  {
     // logic code here
  }
   else
  {
     this.Page.ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "alert", "alert('You pressed  NO!')", true);
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

Implement Confirmation Dialog Box Using Javascript

Please refer given URL

http://www.freshcodehub.com/Article/47/implement-confirmation-dialog-box-using-javascript